# how to set up url routing with sub-paths

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i am new to webapi and MVC in general. If I wanted to group my service URLs like this

- /api/account/create
- /api/account/login
- /api/account/resetpass

Am I able to put all 3 method calls in the same controller file and somehow map a particular request to the right method?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Controller named `Account` and Create 3 [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE] method  and name them `create , login ,resetpass`.
By Default, this is the routing for MVC / API(Id can be optional)
`route Template: "api/{controller}/{id}",`

Example :

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
        [HttpPost]
        public string Create()
        {
            // CODE
        }

        [HttpPost] // or  [HttpGet] 
        public string Login ()
        {
            // CODE
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Resetpass()
        {
            // CODE
        }
}
```

if you had trouble calling them, try to give them a specific route :

```
        [HttpGet("GetSubject/{subject}")]
        public int GetSubjectId(String subject)
        {

          //CODE
        }
```

Please if you get any error or misunderstanding, don't hesitate to post a comment